# {--dex --force-jumbo --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list}

Tags: android, android-studio

When I use the Android studio to package the signed APK, the following error appears. I tried 1, looking for repeated jar packages; 2, configuring build.gradle files; 3, inheriting MultiDexApplication according to the official custom application. But none of them solved the problem.Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --force-jumbo --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list E:\work\sourcecode\zhuoying\20180207\topdraw\android\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\release\maindexlist.txt --output E:\work\sourcecode\zhuoying\20180207\topdraw\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\release\0 --min-sdk-version 16 E:\work\sourcecode\zhuoying\20180207\topdraw\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\release\0.jar}